# Listening to SWT.OpenDocument event from within a plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have read lots of differemt documentation about the launcher.openFile feature of eclipse. They contain information about how to add a listener for the `SWT.OpenDocument` event to react on files that were opened from outside. This always includes adding the listener inside the `Application` class of the eclipse product.

What i want to do is to add such a listener from within my plugin where i don't have an `Application` class at all. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in your plugin? It is not clear that SWT.OpenDocument is the right thing to use.

Comment: There is a batch file which opens files in eclipse with the launcher.openFile feature. What i want to do is react inside my plugin when a file is opened from outside in this way. (It may also be sufficient to listen to opened files in eclipse in general and determine what to do from the fileName).